# SBT dependency on opennlp-tools

Tags: sbt, opennlp

If I have

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.opennlp" % "opennlp-tools" % "1.5.2-incubating"
```

in `build.sbt`, I get an error:

```
[warn]  module not found: jwnl#jwnl;1.3.3
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   C:\Users\Alexey\.ivy2/local/jwnl/jwnl/1.3.3/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/jwnl/jwnl/1.3.3/jwnl-1.3.3.pom
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: jwnl#jwnl;1.3.3: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[error] {file:/E:/OpenCorporaSegmenter/}default-af76b3/*:update: sbt.ResolveExce
ption: unresolved dependency: jwnl#jwnl;1.3.3: not found
[error] Total time: 2 s, completed 22.02.2013 11:53:16
```

The reason is clearly https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OPENNLP-510, but replacing the dependency with

```
libraryDependencies += "org.cleartk" % "cleartk-opennlp-tools" % "0.10.2"
```

(which excludes JWNL), as suggested in the comments there, still produces the same error. Is there a way to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"To exclude certain transitive dependencies of a dependency, use the excludeAll or exclude methods..." — see http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Library-Management.html for further details.